# direct-message using TwitterOauth

Tags: twitter-oauth

I am using following method but its not working.

```
$twitteroauth->post('direct_messages/new', array(
    'text' => 'dm text here',
    'screen_name' => 'recipients screen_name',
));
```

Comment: What doesn't work ? What does the function return ?

Comment: Now Its working fine but only for people who follows the user [who is sending the message]. I need to send to message to any user Please suggest.

Comment: That's not possible. You can only send direct messages to people who follow you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                            $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

// $message must have the @name of the user who created the message 
// referenced in the 'in_reply_to_status_id' field
$tweet = array('status' => $message,
               'in_reply_to_status_id' =>$tweetback['tw_topicid']); 

// post the tweet
$response = $twitter->post('statuses/update', $tweet);
```